# Image sprite in inline style?

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I am able to use image sprites (@sprite) successfully by explicitly defining a ClientBundle with sibling CssResource and ImageResource accessors. However I'm wondering whether using a sprite means that *must* have a separate .css file. If I define my styles inline with `<ui:style>`, how do I get a known name for an image accessor to use with `gwt-image:`?

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question:

```
<ui:style>
   @sprite .panel {
      gwt-image: "titleBackground";
   }
</ui:style>

<ui:image field='titleBackground' src="constants/title-bg.jpg" />
```

The field names of image resources in the same template serve as the names of image accessor functions in the generated client bundle.